# iphone NSFilemanager not creating file

Tags: iphone, nsfilemanager

I'm using NSFileManager to create a file at a specified path with text view contents.
I'm using following code

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:saveFileName contents:[[tView text] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] attributes:nil];
```

But the problem is that, its creating file with no contents. I'm sure that text contents are not nil.
How can I check and confirm that data is written into file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggestions:

1. Capture the BOOL return of the line to make sure it is completing.
2. Log the value of `[tView text]` to make sure it is not empty.
3. ASCII encoding can cause problems these days. Try `NSUTF8StringEncoding` or `NSUTF16StringEncoding`.

Localization may be a problem with plain ASCII encoding because ASCII does not handle multibyte character encodings.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I know it's few months late, but you're sending NSString instead of NSData to the `contents:` parameter.

Try:

```
[[tView text] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

Comment: as my text is pure english, its sufficient to use ASCII encoding.